# Where to create model when using Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model, asp.net-web-api2

I've been checking quite a few examples related to Web Api, and they all create the model in the Models folder contained with the Web Api project but I'm curious as to how this should be handled if you want to use/re-use these models with various projects.

In the past, when using WCF REST, I would have created the following:

1. Business Model Project (PCL)
2. Business Layer Project
3. Data Layer Project
4. SQL Data Layer Project
5. WCF REST Project
6. Web App
7. Windows App
8. Third-Party Web app (javascript)
9. Mobile App (Xamarin)

Projects 2 to 9 would have all been referenced to Project 1 or objects would be created dynamically when using JavaScript. The business object project only contained POCO objects, most decorated with DataContract/DataMember attributes.

Can the same logic/Project breakdown be applied when using Web Api? Is it recommended or will I face problem at a later stage?

If it's not recommended, am I suppose to duplicate all my models? Doesn't seem to make sense so I thought I'd ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, YES. The same logic/Project breakdown can be applied when using Web Api. This is also how I implement my architecture. Your Web Api would just be another layer in your architecture. By doing it that way you will allow for greater re-usability of the models (DRY) and maintainability.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. One more question, I want to use EF as my data layer and while I'll keep as simple as possible for now, a lot of the fields will be decorated with various EF attributes. How should this be handled if it is kept in a separate library? Just reference the DataAnnotation and be done with it? What about JSON formatting via NewtonSoft? I've created a sample where these NewtonSoft were required and I was able to return xml or json and this is obviously the ideal scenario, but what if... Is it a case of referencing Newtonsoft to the Business Objects lib as well? Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing your poco business models to EF (Code first) or are you mapping them to the EF models?

Comment: I haven't started yet. I'm gather information before jumping in. If my POCO business objects are going to be in a separate library, what should be the appropriate action. Pass them to EF or should I be mapping them to EF models? Thanks